# Same data members in base and derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am implementing my own BST and AVL trees.

BSTree inherits Dictionary class. Dictionary class is abstract i.e only provides pure virtual function to be implemented inthe classes which inherit Dictionary. Now, I implemented class BSTree and inherited it in class AVL. Both classes have root as private member. BSTree works completely fine. But put function in AVL is "misbehaving".

This is Dictionary.hpp :

```
#ifndef DICTIONARY_HPP_
#define DICTIONARY_HPP_
template<class Key, class Value>
class Dictionary
{
public:
    virtual ~Dictionary(){};
    virtual void put(const Key& key, const Value& value) = 0;
};
#endif
```

This is BSTree.hpp :

```
 #ifndef BSTREE_HPP
 #define BSTREE_HPP
 #include "Dictionary.hpp"
 
 namespace ntl{
 
 template<class Key,class Value>
 class Node{
     public:
         Key key;
         Value value;
         int height;
         Node *left;
         Node *right;
         Node *parent;
         Node();
 };
    
 template<class Key,class Value>
 Node<Key,Value>::Node(){
     key=defaultData(key);
     value=defaultData(value);
     height=0;
     left=right=parent=NULL;
 }
 
template <class Key, class Value>
class BSTree : public Dictionary<Key, Value> {
private:
    Node<Key,Value> *root;
    int n;
public:
    BSTree();
    bool has(const Key& key);
    void put(const Key& key, const Value& value);
};

template<class Key,class Value>
BSTree<Key,Value>::BSTree(){
    root=NULL;
    n=0;
}

template<class Key,class Value>
bool BSTree<Key,Value>::has(const Key& key){
    //return true if key is present
    //return false if key isn't present
}

emplate<class Key, class Value>
void BSTree<Key,Value>:: put(const Key& key, const Value& value){
    Node<Key,Value> * y=NULL;
    Node<Key,Value> * x=this->root;
    while(x!=NULL){
        y=x;
        if(key<x->key){
            x=x->left;
        }else if(key>x->key){
            x=x->right;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(x!=NULL){
        x->value=value;
    }else{
        Node<Key,Value> *newNode=new Node<Key,Value>(key,value);
        newNode->height=0;
        newNode->parent=y;
        if(y==NULL){
            root=newNode;
        }else if(newNode->key<y->key){
            y->left=newNode;
        }else{
            y->right=newNode;
        }
        n++;
        int lh,rh;
        while(newNode!=NULL){
            if(newNode->left==NULL)
                lh=-1;
            else
                lh=newNode->left->height;
            if(newNode->right==NULL)
                rh=-1;
            else
                rh=newNode->right->height;
            if(lh>rh)
                newNode->height=1+lh;
            else
                newNode->height=1+rh;
            newNode=newNode->parent;
        }
    }
}
```

This is AVL.hpp :

```
#ifndef AVL_HPP
#define AVL_HPP
#include "BSTree.hpp"

namespace ntl{

template <class Key,class Value>
class AVL : public BSTree<Key, Value> {
  private:
      Node<Key,Value> *root;
      int n;
  public:
      AVL();
      virtual void put(const Key& key, const Value& value);
};

template<class Key,class Value>
void AVL<Key,Value>::put(const Key& key, const Value& value){
  std::cout<<"Put function of AVL called\n";
  if(this->root==NULL){
    std::cout<<"Root is NULL\n";
    BSTree<Key,Value>::put(key,value);
  }else if(this->has(key)){
    BSTree<Key,Value>::put(key,value);
  }else{
    //Some More Stuff
  }
}
#endif
```

In main.cpp I did something like :

```
ntl::AVL<int,int> t;
t.put(50,1);
t.put(30,2);
t.put(10,3);
```

I am getting output:

> Put function of AVL called
>
> Root is NULL
>
> Put function of AVL called
>
> Root is NULL
>
> Put function of AVL called
>
> Root is NULL

Why is root always NULL. Numbers are being inserted properly (I have printed them using a custom print function). I guess work is always being done on root variable of BSTree. How to avoid that?
Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

The template class `AVL` has its own private root:

```
    class AVL : public BSTree<Key, Value> {
    private:
         Node<Key,Value> *root;
    ...
```

So does the template class `BSTree`:

```
    class BSTree : public Dictionary<Key, Value> {
    private:
        Node<Key,Value> *root;
    ...
```

While you seem to update the `BSTree::root` correctly in `BSTree::put()`,  the `AVL::root` is another member variable that remains unaffected by these insertion using its base class' `BSTree::put()`:

```
    ...  
    if(this->root==NULL){
        std::cout<<"Root is NULL\n";
        BSTree<Key,Value>::put(key,value);  // if this succeeds, BSTRee's root will be non null
    ...                                     // but AVL's root is unchanged
```

### The solution:

Get rid of AVL's root as apparently it isn't needed.

THen you have the choice:

- make BSTree's root protected, so that AVL has access to it.
- or make a protected (or public) getter in BSTree, so that AVL can get the root's value without being able to change it.